# Compact $\mathbb R$ Support Homework

Tags: measure-theory

Shows that all compact of $\mathbb R$ is the support of a Borel measure.

Comment. For a measure $\mu$ I have to shows that

$supp(\mu)$ = $K$.

If $\mu(X) = 0$, then all compact satisfy $\mu(K) = 0$.

If $\mu(X)< +\infty$ then exists $M \in \mathbb R$ that $\mu(X) = M$, next

supp $\mu$ = $Cl{[\mu \neq 0  ]} = Cl\{ x \in X, \mu(x) > 0, \mu(x)\leq M\} = Cl( \mu^{-1}(0,M])$. Where $( \mu^{-1}(0,M])$ is a borel set.

Next, inside that open set we can find a compact K and then $ K \subset supp(\mu) $.

On other hand, $X = \bigcup^{\infty} K_n$ and then $ supp(\mu) \subset \bigcup^{\infty} K_n$.

Well this is that I think, is convincing?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not convincing at all. You are supposed to construct a measure $\mu$ which is supported in $K$. Where is this measure?

Comment: Think of counting measure.

Comment: I'm still thinking, following the suggestion. Let $\mu$ counting measure. 

If $\mu(A) = \infty$ then $A$ is infinity then take $K = \bigcup K_{n}$ we have $supp(\mu) \subset K$.

If $\mu(A)< \infty$ then $A$ is finite, then take each point of $A$ and let $K = \bigcup_{a\in A} \{a\}$ is a compact, then $supp(A) = K$.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're doing, what does $A$ have to do with this?

Comment: What did you mean with counting measure, I don't understand. I know the definition of this, but, how to work with it?

Comment: @Malaq: For a compact set $K$, what can you say about $\mu_K(A)=\mu(A\cap K)$? where $A$ is any set and $\mu$ is counting measure. What is the support of $\mu_K$?

Comment: @Jose27: Let $K [a,b]$, for this case take a Lebesgue measure restricted to this set, and zero out of this. Let $K$ a point ${a}$, take the measure $δ_a$. Let $K$ a Cantor set take the Cantor function $C(x)$, then the Cantor measure, it is the same thing that I saw in [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20914/confused-about-cantor-function-and-measure-of-cantor-set). Ok in this cases I can solve this exercises, but in a general case. How is the procedure?

Comment: @Malaq: As I said before, try looking at what happens to counting measure restricted to $K$ (meaning, do the same you did for Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ but with counting measure and $K$ instead of $[a,b]$).

Comment: @Jose27: The support of $\mu_K = K.$ 

If $K$ is a subset of $A$, $K\subset A$

$$\mu|_K(A)= \mu(K).$$

If 
$$A\cap K= \emptyset$$ 

then $\mu_K(A) = 0$.

Then for all subset 
$$A \subset K$$ 

$\mu_K > 0$.